# How to figure out timeout error(504), Nothing in logs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, web-server, timeout

I'm getting a lot of timeout errors (504) in my website. I checked almost all the logs and couldn't find anything. There are two websites pointing to the same web app and only one encounters error. Even when one website is returning the timeout error, the other will be working fine.Both use the same code.Only the website which have traffic returns the timeout error. The web app is coded in symfony framework. I checked the mysql slow log and there it was empty.Checked the mysqld logs also and there was nothing that indicated a timed out

How should I go on about finding the issue?

Comment: Have you checked the apache error log ? Time outs are usually logged there. 
Add this setting to  mod_reqtimeout :

RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,minrate=500
RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500

Comment: I checked the apache error logs.I found a lot of entries like the following
[Tue Nov 15 06:45:05.698370 2016] [core:notice] [pid 9729:tid 140573738080384] AH00052: child pid 1803 exit signal Segmentati
on fault (11)

Which file should i add that setting, I am new to this and dont know much about server maintenance.
 I am using RHEL 7.3

Comment: Using apache 2.4

Comment: Edit :  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. Increase the time-out from 300 to 600.

Comment: it didnt help, but i noticed that the mysqld service is using above 100% of the cpu almost all of the peak traffic times. I used the top command to check this. I have enabled the mysql slow logs and it is empty. Is there any way to reduce the cpu usage of mysql